# Why do extensions/WebView impact performance so much? and how to prevent?

Tags: qlikview

I am currently using the SVG map extension and I am noticing that whenever I turn on the WebView my Qlikview file suddenly doesn't react as fast as it used to. The difference is quite large, sometimes it makes everything 2 to 3 times slower compared to when I turn WebView off.

What is the cause of this and is there any way I can prevent this? Is it because of the SVG map extension and should I just use a different one (open to suggestions!)? Or is it because of WebView?

It's also good to know that my Qlikview document isn't all too complex/large (just some charts/donuts etc.) and runs great without the extension/WebView

Thanks in advance,

CvP

Answer (score 1):

This is just a theory, when you turn web view on there is a web browser that renders the objects on screen which means that everything must be translated to web code.

During "normal" mode everything is rendered by qlik's engine and it is probably optimized for speed.

Comment: + the web view is IE powered